# Proof for angle between two curves formula.

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Could someone please provide the proof for the formula attached in the image below? The formula is to find the angle between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ upon intersection.

$\tan a = g'(x)$

$\tan b = f'(x)$

Let $c =a-b$

then $\tan c = \tan (a-b) = \frac{\tan a - \tan b}{1 + (\tan a)(\tan b)}$

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what do you not understand of the above ?

Comment: @GCab I don't understand how the derivatives are used to calculate the angle of intersection.

Comment: $\tan a$ is the angle formed by the tangent of $g(x)$ with the $x$-axis; both are equal to the slope at that point.

Comment: Which formula precisely ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of intuition I've derived: (please let me know if this is incorrect)

[image]

Comment: right, with due consideration for which angle (acute \ obtuse) you are dealing with